# Why is Visual Studio SQL Server database project throwing SQL71501 errors when the target SQL Server is not

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

In SQL Server 2017, I have the following snippet of code in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT d.DocumentID 
FROM Documents d 
INNER JOIN ProductDocuments pd ON d.DocumentID = pd.DocumentID
ORDER BY DocumentID
```

I have just created a database project in Visual Studio 2017 (targeting SQL Server 2017) and imported the structure from my database. Note that the actual query is more complicated but when I strip it down to this I still have the problem in question. Which is that the database project throws a 71501 error on the `DocumentID` in the `ORDER BY` but I get no errors running the code in the database.

I understand why I got the error. I should have `ORDER BY d.DocumentID`. If this was the only error, I would just make that change. But I have dozens of similar issues and I want to get the database project compiled and deployed to a local database and pushed to our repository without having to fix things that SQL Server allows. I have tried putting 71501 in the suppress T-SQL warnings property for this object but that doesn't remove the error, even after cleaning, closing and re-opening and trying to build again.

It seems like SSDT is enforcing something more strict that SQL Server is. Is there any kind of setting that will allow it to still build and compile and find "real" errors, without these false negatives?

Comment: have you found the solution of this problem? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I never found the problem. After going through all the issues I realized that all but a few of the related issues were for procs which are obsolete. SO I just fixed the few remaining issues and removed the obsolete procs. Sorry I don't have a better answer.